# Incorrect height and area for intersection rectangle in Java

Tags: java, geometry, intersection

I am solving a [rectangle geometry USACO problem](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=759) and have an issue when calculating the intersection area of two rectangles.

***Summing up the problem for you***, you are given three rectangles' lower-left coordinates and upper-right coordinates, and you are asked to find the remaining area of the first two rectangles (board1 and board2) after the third rectangle (truck) blocked them partially.

Below is a my code to approach this question.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class BlockedBillboard {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Getting inputs

        // (x1,y1) is the lower-left coordinate (x2, y2) is the upper-right coordinate
        // (x1,y2) is the upper-left coordinate to initialize the rectangles on graph.
        Rectangle board1 = new Rectangle(b1x1, b1y2, b1x2-b1x1, b1y2-b1y1);
        Rectangle board2 = new Rectangle(b2x1, b2y2, b2x2-b2x1, b2y2-b2y1);
        Rectangle truck = new Rectangle(tx1, ty2, tx2-tx1, ty2-ty1);

        // Creating rectangles that result from the intersections 
        Rectangle tb1 = board1.intersection(truck);
        Rectangle tb2 = board2.intersection(truck);
        int blocked = 0;

        // The truck may or may not block the boards
        if(!tb1.isEmpty())
            blocked += (int) (tb1.getWidth() * tb1.getHeight());
        if(!tb2.isEmpty())
            blocked += (int) (tb2.getWidth() * tb2.getHeight());

        int area = (int) (board1.getWidth() * board1.getHeight()) + 
                    (int) (board2.getWidth() * board2.getHeight()) - 
                    blocked;

        pw.println(area);
        pw.close();     
    }
}
```

After a few tests I find the area of board1 and board2 to be correct, but the problem occurs when **calculating the intersection area** between the boards and the truck.

I further investigated by printing out the width and height of the intersection rectangles, and I found the **widths are correct but the heights are wrong**.

I wonder if I used the intersection method correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you referring to class [java.awt.Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html)?

Comment: @Abra Yes, I'm referring to java.awt.Rectangle

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I think I understand what is going on. My algorithm is logical, but I didn't understand how a rectangle works in Java.

In Java, a rectangle is plotted on a GUI plane known as ***canvas***. The origin (0,0) of a canvas **starts at the upper-left corner** instead of lower-left corner.

In other words, the height becomes more positive when **it goes down** the vertical axis of a canvas. Nevertheless, the width holds true as before (becomes more positie when it goes right on the horizontal axis).

**With that being said, a rectangle's upper-left corner on a normal coordinate plane is same as the lower-left corner on a canvas.** So I should enter **y1** for the second parameter when intializing the rectangles.

```
Rectangle board1 = new Rectangle(b1x1, b1y1, b1x2-b1x1, b1y2-b1y1);
Rectangle board2 = new Rectangle(b2x1, b2y1, b2x2-b2x1, b2y2-b2y1);
Rectangle truck = new Rectangle(tx1, ty1, tx2-tx1, ty2-ty1);
```